# is the function $f$ continuous when we replace the statement of continuity definition by this?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

We know that a function $f:\, D\to\mathbb R\ \,(D\subset\mathbb R)$ is continuous at $x$ iff
\begin{align}
\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\,\delta>0:\ \big|f(y)-f(x)\big|<\varepsilon,\ \forall y\in D:\ |y-x|<\delta.
\end{align}

But, what happens if we change the statement "$ \forall y\in D:\ |y-x|<\delta$" to "$\forall y\in\mathbb Q\cap D:\ |y-x|<\delta$", or more general, "$ \forall y\in I\cap D:\ |y-x|<\delta$" for some dense subset $I\subset\mathbb R$ ? Should $f$ be continuous at $x$ in this case, or is there any counter example ?

I hope anyone will enlight me with this querry. Thanks

Comment: The indicator of $\Bbb Q$, i.e. $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, would be a counter example, isn't it?

Comment: In some sense, it's okay. This shows that $f$ is continuous on $I$. If $f$ is also uniformly continuous on $I$, then $f$ admits a unique continuous extension to $\bar I$

Answer (score 1):

No. For a counterexample, define $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & \text{ if }x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
1 & \text{ if }x\notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}.$$

Consider now a fixed $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Since the irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $\delta >0$ there exists a $y\in D$ such that $|x-y| = 1$. Hence, $f$ is not continuous in the normal sense. However, if we restrict ourselves to $y\in \mathbb{Q}\cap D$, then the condition does hold.

In general, if we consider a dense subset $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, the same argument will hold for any $I$ whose complement is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

In fact, consider $I =\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x<0\}\cap \{x\in \mathbb{Q}:x\geq 0\}$. The complement of $I$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but it fails continuity for any $x>0$ for the analogous $f$ defined as above, but does satisfy the alternate continuity definition at such $x$. The problem arises from the fact that we still have a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ on which the complement of $I$ is dense. Informally, what we have argued here is that for the two definitions to agree, we need $I$ to have a nowhere dense complement.

Comment: Does your last statement imply that for any dense subset with a non-dense complement, this will be equivalent to normal continuity? I'm not sure this is true, it probably is true if the complement is nowhere dense

Comment: I added some details with regards to this to my answer @Carlyle

Comment: does our alternate continuity definition generate a topology ?